# DNS Timing Out on Machine

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dns

Major problem here that I cant figure out!  pandlstrategies.com works fine on some machines and in some locations, but keeps timing out on others, mine being one of them.  I can not get to my domain and the major problem is I cant download email using Outlook.

When I go to a web mail program such as Yahoo or Live I can retrieve my email from my mail server using this machine but when I try to use Outlook it tells me name server not found.

I ran `ipconfig / flushdns` and then nslookup and here is what I got:

```
Nslookup pandlstrategies.com

server:  pandlstrategies.com

address:  66.185.28.159

dns request timed out

time out was 2 seconds

request to pandlstrategies.com timed-out
```

I work all day in email and I REALLY need to be able to use Outlook.  Machine is XP with SP3 using Outlook Express 2003

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called NameBench to check your DNS servers and find faster/more accurate ones. [NameBench Site](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/)

You can also run [Netalyzer](http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/index.html) to see if there is a larger problem with your network.

Comment: The mailserver works on my partners machine just fine.  She is having no problems whatsoever with it.  Others can reach my page from their machines, but I cant.  This has to be something local, isnt it?

Comment: You could always double check your personal firewall, but running Netalyzer could show where a misconfiguration might be on a local machine.

Comment: Netalyzer found nothing except:

Comment: Major Abnormalities Your DNS resolver returns results even when no such server exists

Comment: Odd. Well, the next step is to do a traceroute to the ip address/dns address of the mail server to make sure you can get there. To do this in the cmd prompt type "tracert mailserver" where mailserver is the ip address or dns address of your company's mail server.

Comment: as it did yesterday it times out at about the 15th hop cyberlynk address is 66.185.29.122

Comment: meant to at cyberlynk.net

Comment: I can ping that address and it responds though

Comment: This may not be related, but you could clean up all the temp files and clean registry errors on your PC and reboot. If that works, Windows was acting funny. You may have to ask your IT Department if there is more configuration needed to access your email from other locations outside of the Intranet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a home machine.

Try using OpenDNS (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) as your DNS Servers (see [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/network/dns.html) if you need instructions on how to change them.

For a business machine, this will work if you are not in a domain, but check with the network admin (unless that is you) before changing.

Comment: home machine used for business.  I changed the DNS but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that your local machine thinks its name is "pandlstrategies.com" - it strikes me as unusual that when you do a nslookup, the server that you're using for the lookup *is* pandlstrategies.com.

Are you running a webserver, a nameserver, and a mail server on the same (XP) machine that you use to run Outlook and otherwise do your daily work?

If so, that is really *not* the right way to do things. Your website and email and other services should be hosted on a fast machine located where there's good bandwidth and servers should never be used as desktops (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed your local DNS?, and checked your hosts file for hijacking?

http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html

Have you reset your tcpip

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357